# Sign PDF using itextsharp and Azure key vault

Tags: itext, azure-keyvault

my pfx file has been imported to Azure key vault, when I get it back as keybundle, it includes public key only.
How to use Azure key vault to sign PDF document by itextsharp

Comment: I don't know a lot about PDF signing but I'd encourage you to read the [152 page PDF by Bruno Lowagie](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html) that goes into great detail on it. You _might_ be able to write your own `Provider` that dispatches over to Azure but you also might want to check that the algorithms used by Azure are supported in both iText as well as the PDF spec.

Answer (score 1):

Key Vault does not export private keys, probably because this would break security requirements. You must compute a digest from a PDF region then call the [Sign with a key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn878096.aspx) REST API. You can also use the [Key Vault .NET client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/) for that. The signature algorithms supported by PDF version 1.6+ [are also supported by Key Vault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn903623.aspx#BKMK_RSA-HSMAlgorithms) . Make sure you understand [PDF signature details](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf).